# Rate of change of angle formed by $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and the origin.

Tags: calculus

the problem I am working on is this.

> Point $P(x,y)$ is on the curve $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$.  The angle formed between the $x$-axis and the line that connects the origin and $P$ is $\theta$.  As $x\rightarrow\infty $, what does $\theta $ approach to? What does the rate of change of the angle approach to?

I am having trouble finding the expression of $\theta$.

I know that after that I take the derivative and let $x \rightarrow \infty$.

May I have some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = \sqrt[3]{x}$

The angle between points $(0,0), (x, \sqrt[3]{x})$ is 
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(x^{-\frac23}\right)$$

As $x \to \infty$, $x^{-\frac23} \to 0$,  $\tan^{-1}\left(x^{-\frac23}\right) \to \tan^{-1}(0) = 0$

The rate at which $\theta$ changes is
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(x^{-\frac23}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + \left(x^{-\frac23}\right)^2}\left(-\frac23x^{-\frac53}\right) = -\frac23\frac{x^{-\frac53}}{1+x^{-\frac43}}$$

Comment: Does this mean that eventually the graph will be almost parallel to the x-axis?

Comment: Exactly. The point gets farther away, and closer to $y = 0$, so the angle drops as well.

Comment: Wait, y is an increasing function, though.

Comment: My mistake I misspoke in comment above. $y' < 1$, so $y/x$ is decreasing as $x$ increases

Comment: Ah, I can actually visualize it now.  That is super cool.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The angle of a line that passes through the origin to a point $(x,y)$ is $\tan^{-1}\dfrac{y}{x}$ (Do you know why? Hint: Draw the line from the point P down to the x axis)